# Segment/profiling in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Help please!!

I was trying to create a column 'Segment' based on the condition:

```
 if 'Pro_vol' >1 and 'Cost' >=43 then append 1 
 if 'Pro_vol' ==1 and 'Cost' >=33 then append 1 
 or append 0
```

Below is the code for data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            'Pro_vol':[1,2,3,1,5,1,2,1,4,5],
              'Cost' : [12.34,13.55,34.00, 19.15,13.22,22.34,33.55,44.00, 29.15,53.22]})
```

I tried a code:

```
Segment=[]

for i in df['Pro_vol']:
if i >1:
    Segment.append(1)
    for j in df['Cost']:
        if j>=43:
            Segment.append(1)
elif i==1:
    Segment.append(1)
elif j>=33:
    Segment.append(1)
else:
    Segment.append(0)

df['Segment']=Segment
```

And it was giving me an error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I don't know any other way to try to find an answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider `np.where`

```
np.where(((df.Cost>=33)&(df.Pro_vol==1))|((df.Cost>=43)&(df.Pro_vol>1)),1,0)
Out[538]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```